# How to make a link appear as a normal link in one screen size, as a button in another?

Tags: html, css, mobile, button, screen

I'm programming a website with three different sizes for desktop, netbook and mobile phone systems.

On the main page I have a click-thru html link of the

```
<a href="more.html">Find out more</a>
```

variety.

What I want is to change this to a button for mobile screens, like a conditional statement or something.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use media queries in CSS. See: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html

Just change the CSS for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

oficial web site about media queries. 
[click here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 1):

for examples:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
/* define mobile specific styles come here */
a {display:block; width:200px; height:50px;} /* here you add style to your link/class ..*/
}
```

or.. if you want to use a  then you can hide this from css for desktop version and show just for mobile

```
/*desktop css*/
a { ... css code ...}
button {display:none}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
/* define mobile specific styles come here */
a {display:none} /* 
button {display:block; ..}
}
```

and a jquery solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

    var $is_mobile = false;

    if( $('#some-element').css('display') == 'none' ) {
        $is_mobile = true;      
    }

    // now i can use $is_mobile to run javascript conditionally
 });
```

For a beter experience, use class instead of html elements

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries. They can help you target type of screen and based on its width. For example

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 300px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    /* Now you can write a different style of elements on a screen with maximum 300px as width */

   a {
      color: #f00; /* Make link appear red on mobile screen */

      /* make it should like a button */
      border: 1px #c00 solid;
      background: #ddd; 
   }
}
```

Note: *Media Queries are CSS3 features, and will not work in earlier version of IE.*